# bounded circular interpolation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

My question is something similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888927/circular-interpolation-in-python). In simple term I have a time series angle data which is bounded between [0, 360]. I need to compute an iterpolation between measurements. Currently, I am using [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html). To make my question clear here is an example,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
data = np.array([[0, 2, 4], [1, 359, 1]]) # first row time index, second row angle measurements
f = interpolate.interp1d(data[0, :], data[1, :], kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)
f([1, 3])
```

this will result in [ 180.,  180.]. However between time 2 and time 4 the angle changed from 359 to 1, that is only a 2 degree change and the interpolated value at 3 should have been 0. The angles are changing in CCW direction through time.

Finally, my question is this,

Is there any standard module that I can use to achieve this?

Just because I want to avoid custom method as much as possible!

Comment: By `standard` do you mean part of a Python distribution or Numpy, SciPy?  Did you spend any time reviewing the documentation?

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean anything in Numpy, SciPy (I don't want to have something that can only be used to solve this specific problem). I have tried to see the documentation, but as you can tell my knowledge on interpolation is not more than linear

Comment: Which *direction* is the angle is changing - *clockwise* or *counterclockwise*?  How is that determined?

Comment: The angle is changing CCW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the 360° complement each time you detect there is a jump and revert back to the first 360 degrees by using the modulo operation. For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy import interpolate

In [3]: data = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 179, 211, 359, 1]])

In [4]: complement360 = np.rad2deg(np.unwrap(np.deg2rad(data[1])))

In [5]: complement360
Out[5]: array([   1.,  179.,  211.,  359.,  361.])

In [6]: f = interpolate.interp1d(data[0], complement360, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)

In [7]: f(np.arange(9))
Out[7]: array([   1.,   90.,  179.,  195.,  211.,  285.,  359.,  360.,  361.])

In [8]: f(np.arange(9))%360
Out[8]: array([   1.,   90.,  179.,  195.,  211.,  285.,  359.,    0.,    1.])
```

Remark, I did add a few extra values here, as otherwise there is no realistic way for `np.unwrap` to know in which direction the angle is increasing, and that is probably also how you know it is increasing in that way (the difference between consecutive values is less than 180° unless there's an actual discontinuity).

If however you really have data that makes angular jumps larger than 180° between 2 consecutive items, but you know the direction in which the angles are changing (e.g. CCW) and that it is changing monotonously, then you could detect it like so:

```
In [31]: data = np.array([1, 359, 1, 60, 359, 177, 2])  # mock-data

In [32]: jumps = np.diff(data)<0  # assumptions: angle increases stricly monotonously CCW

In [33]: np.hstack((data[0], data[1:] + np.cumsum(np.sign(d)<0)*360))
Out[33]: array([   1,  359,  361,  420,  719,  897, 1082])
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.10.0, numpy.interp takes a period keyword: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Comment: The period keyword for numpy.interp is for x-axis periodicity, not y-axis periodicity, so it doesn't seem that this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code does exactly what you ask for. First, it unwraps the angles such that there never is a jump larger than 180 degrees between consecutive values (see [MATLAB's nice documentation for unwrap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html)), then interpolation is performed, and finally `np.mod` is used such that the returned angles are in the interval [0, 360).

```
import numpy as np

def circular_interpolation(x: np.ndarray, xp: np.ndarray, fp: np.ndarray, period: float = 360) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    One dimensional linear interpolation for monotonically increasing sample points where points first are unwrapped,
    secondly interpolated and finally bounded within the specified period.
    
    :param x: The x-coordinates at which to evaluate the interpolated values.
    :param xp: The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing.
    :param fp: The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as `xp`.
    :param period: Size of the range over which the input wraps.
    :return: The interpolated values, same shape as `x`.
    """
    
    y = np.mod(np.interp(x, xp, np.unwrap(fp, period=period)), period)
    return y
```

---

Note that the `period` option for `np.unwrap` is new in version 1.21.0 of Numpy. For older versions of Numpy, you could convert to radians before performing the interpolation.